# Why does this if statement not get executed?

Tags: javascript, json, for-in-loop

I'm trying to return the number of users that are online as determined by this JS object. However, my counter for users that are currently online never gets incremented.

I use the for-in loop to iterate through the JS object, and then I increment the 'usersOnline' variable if the specific user's 'online' property is set to true.

```js
let users = {
  Alan: {
    age: 27,
    online: false
  },
  Jeff: {
    age: 32,
    online: true
  },
  Sarah: {
    age: 48,
    online: false
  },
  Ryan: {
    age: 19,
    online: true
  }
};

function countOnline(obj) {
  let usersOnline = 0;

  for (let user in obj) {
    if (user.online === true)
      usersOnline++;
  }

  return usersOnline;
}

console.log(countOnline(users));
```

usersOnline should be incremented twice so that it is equal to 2. But it stays set at 0. This problem is part of a coding challenge on freeCodeCamp.com I'm more interested in why this specific code won't work versus how to use JS objects in general.

Comment: A `for ... in` loop iterates through the **keys** of the object, not the values.

Comment: Small note: it's a bad practice to check `if (something === true)`. Instead, just check `if (something)`.

Comment: I understand that this probably isn't the best practice for any real tasks, but I'm more interested in learning what about this specific code isn't working, I don't really need info on how to use JS objects in general.

Comment: That is easily discovered by looking at the documentation for [`for...in` loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) (or even just `console.log(user)` to check its value), where you will see that it loops through the property *names*, not the property values.

Comment: The for in loop was actually working perfectly. I just needed to go a level deeper when checking the object's values.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to `reduce()` the `values()` of the `users` object to obtain a total number of users that are online:

```js
let users = {
  Alan: {
    age: 27,
    online: false
  },
  Jeff: {
    age: 32,
    online: true
  },
  Sarah: {
    age: 48,
    online: false
  },
  Ryan: {
    age: 19,
    online: true
  }
};

const onlineCount = Object.values(users).reduce((total, user) => {
  /* If user is online, add 1 to the total, otherwise add 0 */
  return total + (user.online ? 1 : 0);
}, 0)

console.log(onlineCount)
```

The `reduce()` works by starting with an initial value of `0`, and iterating all user values returned by `Object.values()`, adding a `1` or `0` to the total in order to obtain the total count of online users.